# Can I set the height of the HTML element via jQuery?

Tags: jquery, css, html, internet-explorer-6

I'm having an issue with IE6 compatibility on a Boilerplate (and HTML5Shiv) project. I've been attempting to set the `<html>` element to be the same height as the `<body>` element but for whatever reason, it is fixed on 100% without any specific code. Each page's length is dynamic so I cannot set specific values.

I want to do this because of one primary reason -- IE6 is not displaying the scrollbar even though there is additional content below.

I've tried to set the height via the following code without any luck:

```
$("html").css("height", parseInt($("body").height()) + "px");
```

I've also attempted the following code and only the `<body>` element responds:

```
$("html, body").css("height", "2000px");
```

However, I have been able to add scrolling through a band-aid fix:

```
html, body {
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Now back to the height problem, is this even possible via `jQuery`? Does IE6 simply not support what I'm after?

Thanks!

Comment: IE6? Do you really want to support that browser?

Comment: Based on experience, I'd rather show a splash page telling the user to upgrade the current browser if the user is using IE

Comment: IE 7 and below are dead. jQuery 2 is going to stop supporting them. Glad to say, in 2013, IE 8 and below have dropped below the 2% market share.

Comment: Appreciate the "don't support IE6" comments, but I do need to make this work as the project user base is almost predominantly IE6. It's not a case of making it to look and work perfectly, all I really want to do is to make the HTML element recognise take on the height of the child BODY element. Seemingly easy, apparently not.

Comment: IE6? That doesn't even support divs, right? ;)

Comment: I'm pretty sure query has a property for height. Use ' $(element).height(insert heighthere)'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm surprised nobody has mentioned this yet.

**Forget trying to size the `<html>` element.**

The `html` element isn't meant to be sized. I wouldn't bother trying to maker a smaller `body` either. If you need an element of a certain size, stick a `div` inside your `body` and style that.

The [HTML4 specification for the `html` tag](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-html401-19991224/struct/global.html#h-7.3) doesn't list `style` as an attribute, and it's easy to understand why.

Even in a modern browser like Chrome, trying to size the `html` element gives slightly odd results: http://jsfiddle.net/QdCmM/.

Comment: Hi Jezen. Thank you for your reply, it certainly makes sense that the `html` tag cannot be modified through CSS styling. In any case, IE6 is exhibiting strange behaviour in that the dimensions of the `body` element are not being shown in the parent `html` element. Regarding entering a `div`, are you meaning this I make it a container as the first child inside `body`?

Comment: Exactly. Use a combination of `div`s in your `body`, and style those instead. If my answer helped you, don't forget to mark it as correct :)

Comment: Hi Jezen, sorry for the lateness of my reply. I tried your method, particularly setting a `div` container as the first child of `body` to encompass all the content on a page. However it still does not cause the `html` element to take on the height of `body` and there are no scrollbars. However, I've done some extra troubleshooting and it looks like my main CSS file has something that is causing it to behave like this. PEBKAC! Thanks all.